# Installing intelligent text completition for gedit on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gedit, 19.10, text-editor

I'm trying to install the package "intelligent text completition 3.8" for gedit by following [this](https://github.com/nymanjens/gedit-intelligent-text-completion) guide:

1. Unpack the archive
2. Put intelligent_text_completion.plugin and intelligent_text_completion.py inside .local/share/gedit/plugins in your home directory. (create it if it doesn't exist yet)
3. (Re)start Gedit.
4. Go to Edit->Preferences->Plugins and check the box for Intelligent Text Completion

The problem is that I didn't find the box Intelligent Text Completition in Edit->Preferences->Plugins. Can you tell me how can I overcome this problem please?

---

EDIT: after I installed the gedit-plugins, the available options are the following:

[image]
[image]

---

EDIT 2: I tried with the command ls -lR ~/.local/share/gedit (idem for ls -alR ~/.local/share/gedit), but the terminal shows me the message "No such file or directory". The strange thing is that I created manually the folders gedit and plugins in the folder .gnome (see the below figure).

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it show up when you type: `ll ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`? I'm wondering if it was unpacked to the wrong place.

Comment: [Gedit is 3.34 on 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gedit). You are installing something that was supposed to work 26 versions ago (gedit 3.8). Last update of that repo is 5 years ago. If I were you, I would find an alternative to gedit if this feature is really needed.

Comment: Hello @WinEunuuchs2Unix, as Dk Bose suggests, I forgot to install gedit-plugins.

Comment: This is the problem: *"The strange thing is that I created manually the folders gedit and plugins in the folder .gnome"*. You should create the `gedit` folder in `~/.local/share` and then create the folder `plugins` in `~/.local/share/gedit`. When you do that correctly, you'll get results for `ls -alR ~/.local/share/gedit`. **Don't put anything into .gnome**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it on 19.10 and it works for me with *gedit 3.34.0* and `https://github.com/nymanjens/gedit-intelligent-text-completion/releases/download/v2.4/intelligent-text-completion-gedit3-8-v2.5.tar.gz`.

The key point maybe is that you first need to install `gedit-plugins` from the 19.10 repositories with `sudo apt install gedit-plugins`.

After doing so, follow the instructions in [your link](https://github.com/nymanjens/gedit-intelligent-text-completion):

[image: Intelligent text completion plugin is listed]

### Note:

This plugin also works in gedit running on Kubuntu 19.10, Ubuntu MATE 19.10 and Xubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Hi @DKBose, now I installed the geidt-plugins, but the option doesn't appear. See the edit please.

Comment: Hi @DK Bose I downloaded the right version , i.e. the one you linked above.

Comment: So now make sure you put the stuff in ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins. Also please post the output of `ls -alR ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`. The plugin even works in Ubuntu Mate 19.10.

Comment: thank you very very much; finally it appears!

Comment: You're most welcome!